# CollectionView Highlights incorrect Cell When Scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UICollectionView`. When an user clicks a cell the colour of the cell changes to red. I have coded the above part and it works perfectly.

However, when I scroll below, other cells in the collection view has got highlighted with the colour red. I am sure that it hasn't been selected but only highlighted.

How can I solve this.

My code is as follows:

**cellForItemAtIndexPath** Method

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

    ViewCell *vc = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    vc.vciv.image = [arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return vc;

}
```

**didSelectItemAtIndexPath** Method

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

    if([items  containsObject:allItem[indexPath.row]] ){
        UICollectionViewCell *c =[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        c.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
    } else {
        UICollectionViewCell *c =[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        c.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; 
 }
```

Comment: You need to keep track of the selected index and make sure you set the cell background color to either red or clear in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the collection view cells get reused, you need to make sure a dequeued cell is not highlighted in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method:

```
UICollectionViewCell *vc = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
vc.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

This code will clear the cell's background always when dequeuing. If you need to preserve the highlighting, you need to store the `indexPath`s of the cells that you want to have highlighted, and check for the current cell being in that list.

**EDIT**

It seems that your `items` variable is well suited to do that.
So you would do:

```
UICollectionViewCell *vc = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
vc.backgroundColor = [items containsObject:allItem[indexPath.row]] ? [UIColor redColor] : [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: Where do you want me to add the above code. Is it in  `didSelectItemAtIndexPath ` ?

Comment: No, in `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` as I've written ;-)